# Cannot Replicate and Resolve EXC_CRASH SIGKILL for Apple Submission

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I recently had an app rejected (first submission) from Apple due to the error message EXC_CRASH SIGKILL. The review comments mentioned the app was crashing on startup. I understand this error could be related to iOS 12, Firebase, or my app simply taking too long to load.

I want to debug, however I am unable to replicate this bug on my end. I have tested straight from xCode deployment and through testFlight, and I am unfortunately not able to replicate. The app is loading without any issues.

How can I ultimately replicate (via testFlight or xCode) and resolve this error?

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code
>   0x8badf00d Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog
>   transgression: ********* exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of
>   17.77 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground |
>   WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 37.550
>   (user 37.550, system 0.000), 63% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time
>   (seconds): 1.015, 2% CPU" | ) Triggered by Thread:  0

Comment: Need code and possibly Firebase structure. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Knowing you cannot replicate the issue, we still need to see the code that your app starts with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is answer https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0 needs to be moved to a background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block the main thread.

And here is reasons of this crash https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: How can I replicate though so that I know if I have resolved? xCode and testFlight are deploying without this error.

Comment: Building upon @Shalyapin 's suggestion, If it is related to networking on main thread then I suggest  simulating the operation on a 2G/3G environment. So despite you having a fast internet connection, you can simulate to run/launch it on slow internet. Networking related operations should always be async. Provide a loading spinner of sorts to indicate user that a data is incoming.

Comment: I assume, you are waiting for network IO on the main thread. Have you tried testing with Network Link Conditioner in Developer section in Settings screen?

Comment: There's discussion here about threading but I am not sure moving code to other threads is a good recommendation without knowing more about the app and the startup sequence. All of Firebase is asynchronous so threading isn't an issue - so it may be some other process. I would suggest including your app delegate code and possibly your first viewController so we can see how the app is starting. Please keep the code brief.